# dataframe.selectexpr performace for selecting large number of columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark dataframe in scala. My data frame is holding about 400 columns, with 1000-1M rows. I am running a 
**datagrame.selectExpr operation(1 to 400th column) on certain criteria** and once fetching them, I am aggregating the values of all these columns.

my selectexpr statement:

`val df = df2.selectExpr(getColumn(beginDate, endDate, x._2): _*)`

getColumn method will fetch columns day wise between start and enddate from my dataframe (this may be 365 columns as we have day wise data).

my summing by expression is :

```
  df.map(row => (row(0), row(1), row(2), (3 until row.length).map(row.getLong(_)).sum)).collect()
```

I find that selecting these many number of columns is degrading the performance of my job. Is there anyway to make this fetching of 400 columns much faster?

Comment: Did you figure out anything on this? Struggling with a similar thing

Answer (score 0):

Dataframe is better optimization than the RDD . And you are using it which is good . But can you Please check the Spark UI and what stage it is taking much time. If its taking the time due to calculation or due to data load. [Reshaping Data](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html) . And try to scale up slowly for faster output.Check if the partioning can also help your code to run it fatser . [Apache Spark Code Faster](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/debug-apache-spark-code-faster-indrajit-swain?trk=prof-post) .Making the code faster depnds on various factor and try to optimize by using those.

Comment: Time is getting consumed during selectExpr() as observed by me. Is there any way that I can give filter condition before loading to dataframe? 
As currently, if I have 1 lakh records in table and I need only 100 of them, I am still loading the whole data into dataframe and then filtering it on a filter condition.

Comment: I am doing a flatmap on set of filters(filters is a set of where conditions that we formed, it is a ParAraay for me in my code) .So this filtering and  selecting is happening paralelly :
'val result = filters.flatMap(x => {
  
      val df1 = sqlContext
        .read
        .format(")
        .options(Map("table" -> "tablename", "keyspace" -> "keyspacename"))
        .load()
        .filter(x._1).selectExpr()
}'
I guess loading 365 columns is making it slow. Could you suggest something on this? Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: As per your comment if you need only 100 record out of 1 lakh record then there is no point to load the whole dataset into Memory . Try to create a record of set of value . And do the not equal comparison to get the required result. Or else load whole dataset and fire the SQL type of query on Dataframe . Dont load whole dataset it will eat up the Memory.

Comment: Load the whole dataset Dataframe and after the fire a SQL query with condition to get only the required fields after that cache those 100 record Dataframe .you will get Better result in performance . paste your code with sample data

Comment: I am loading data from table and then filtering only required rows. Then I am selecting 400 columns from each of the required rows. My performance is getting affected while picking 400 columns. 


`val df1 = sqlContext
        .read
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(Map("table" -> "usage", "keyspace" -> "abc"))
        .load()
        .filter(x._1).selectExpr(getColumn(beginDate, endDate, x._2): _*)`

Comment: sample data :
`account1  2015 customer1 plan 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 0 ..... 432`

Here numeric values from 1-432 is the value per day for given year. I need to select these columns for filtered rows.

There can be millions of those filtered records.

Comment: If there is nothing can be mapped and it is very dynamic then do check the data Partition it is creating and try to cache the Data .spark.cacheTable("tableName") or dataFrame.cache() and once you done after that invoke spark.uncacheTable("tableName").Check also persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_ONLY).